# How to configure microk8s with mayastor pools

Tags: microk8s

I have one Microk8s cluster with 4 bare metal. I want to configure a Mayastor to get redundancy when a one node fail.

I want to separate my disks with logical volumes and to bind to mayastor pools.

I created the pools on each machine like this and bind to logical volume formated with xfs system.

```
g0004830@p-br-pr-cta-gt2-mk8s-01:~$ microk8s.kubectl -n mayastor get dsp
NAME                                      NODE                      STATUS   CAPACITY      USED   AVAILABLE
pool-p-br-pr-cta-gt2-mk8s-01-gitness-lv   p-br-pr-cta-gt2-mk8s-01   Online   21449670656   0      21449670656
pool-p-br-pr-cta-gt2-mk8s-02-gitness-lv   p-br-pr-cta-gt2-mk8s-02   Online   21449670656   0      21449670656
pool-p-br-pr-cta-gt2-mk8s-03-gitness-lv   p-br-pr-cta-gt2-mk8s-03   Online   21449670656   0      21449670656
pool-p-br-pr-cta-gt2-mk8s-04-gitness-lv   p-br-pr-cta-gt2-mk8s-04   Online   21449670656   0      21449670656
```

I readed some tutorials but I do not understand how to storage class bind to disk pools.

Summary, I want to deploy a POD (example gitness application with 20Gb) with data redundant using a dedicate logical volume. If a node where my application is running fail, I need running pod in another node with same data from fail node.